# TEXTIO : Read past end of file in ModelSim Simulation

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

```
architecture Behavioral of INST_CACHE is

        subtype word is std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);
        type storage_array is array (0 to 2*16 - 1) of word;
        --type storage_array is array (0 to 2**10 - 1) of STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (DATA_WIDTH - 1 downto 0);

        signal InstCacheOut1_t  : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (DATA_WIDTH - 1 downto 0); -- data output line 1
        signal InstCacheOut2_t  : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (DATA_WIDTH - 1 downto 0); -- data output line 2

        type load_file_type is file of word;
        file load_file : text open read_mode is "D:\instcachecontent.txt";

        shared variable storage : storage_array;

begin

    clk_part : process (CLK, RST)

        variable index      : natural;
        variable rdline     : line;
        variable char       : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);

    begin


        if (RST = '1') then


                -- load ROM contents from load_file
                index := 0;
                readline(load_file, rdline);
                while not endfile(load_file) loop
                    readline(load_file, rdline);
                    hread(rdline, storage(index)(63 downto 32));
                    read(rdline, char);
                    read(rdline, storage(index)(31 downto 0));
                    index := index + 1;
                end loop;

        elsif (clk'event and clk = '1') then

            InstCacheOut1 <= InstCacheOut1_t;
            InstCacheOut2 <= InstCacheOut2_t;

        end if;

    end process;

end Behavioral;
```

Above is my architecture design.
I'm not supposed to synthesize it, only simulate it in ModelSim.

However, during run, I get this error:

> Fatal: (vsim-3551) TEXTIO : Read past end of file "D:\instcachecontent.txt".

the line the error is reported at is (before the loop)

```
        readline(load_file, rdline);
```

This is the content of the file:

```
00000010
00000010    01111000000000100000000000000001
00000011    01111000000000000001000000000000
00000012    10100000000001000000000000000000
00000013    00001000100001000001000000000000
00000014    11010111111111111111111111111110
00000015    10101000000001000000000000000000
00000016    11111000000000000000000000000000
```

Any help would be appreciated, since I don't know how can it read past end of file on the first line.

Comment: Which occurrence of that line triggers the error? The one in the loop or the one before it?

Comment: You can't read a file multiple times. This will occur if RST is one.

Comment: @Brian Drummond
Before the loop.

Comment: Notice Brian's and Patrick's comments both address the same issue. The first `readline(load_file, rdline);` is not protected by a `not endfile(load_file)` condition. If `RST = '1'` and there's a second event (on `CLK`) the first readline will fail the second time. You could have the first one conditional on `index = 0`.

Comment: @Paebbels The reset signal will be active only at the beginning of the simulation. It's like an init signal. Can I do this another way, so I can read the files accordingly?

Comment: @user1155120

That first readline is simply to read the first line of file, because I want to skip that line. I don't need to store that line anywhere.
  
Can I skip the first line of the file in some other way?

Comment: It's obvious that's what you were doing, no there's no other way to skip the line. Without enough of your code to model it appears you are executing the `RST = '1'` conditioned code more than once, the second time after hitting end of file the first time through. Note that you can't re-read a file by invoking `RST` without an intervening `FILE_CLOSE` (and that also implies detecting a transition on `RST` from `'0'` to `'1'` instead of level. Use `rising_edge(RST)` which actually requires the transition.)

Comment: You could read and parse your file into a constant and initialize your signals with that content. It's also possible to reuse that content in reset cases. By the way: Normally cache contents can't be reseted. There is a valid bit for such a requirement.

Comment: There's not enough declarations visible to determine cache architecture (nor the best course of action, which is why you see these comments instead of an answer).

Comment: @Paebbels, can I set the value of index to 0 when declaring it, and then inside if just check `if index = 0`, and skip the first line then.

I think that's what you meant in your first comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry to bypass all the comments but to me the solution to this doesn't really depend on anything. You have not got `if (rising_edge(RST)) then <ROM init loop>`, but `if (RST = '1') then <ROM init loop>`. Since you have `CLK` in the sensitivity list for the process, any change in `CLK` while `RST` is high, will cause the loop to run again, causing the error you've seen.

You can easily make sure this happens only once with a boolean variable:

```
variable rom_init_complete : boolean := false;
```

...

```
if (not rom_init_complete) then
  -- load ROM contents from load_file
  rom_init_complete := true;
  index := 0;
  readline(load_file, rdline);
  while not endfile(load_file) loop
    readline(load_file, rdline);
    hread(rdline, storage(index)(63 downto 32));
    read(rdline, char);
    read(rdline, storage(index)(31 downto 0));
    index := index + 1;
  end loop;
end if;
```